# Don't want distance between items of Listactivity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

[image]

my xml for **report layout**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    </ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/main_no_items"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

As you seen in image that there is unnecessary distance between list items. I try everything to minimize the distance between the list item but it never decrease:( I want that no gap between two items. Kindly guide how can i get next item after one list item with no gap except the partition line.

Comment: in your row, you have a wrap_content vertical linearlayout that contains 4 weight=1 textviews. You can understand how this can be confusing for the layout measurement. remove the weight and use wrap_content height for you textviews.

Comment: i do it but not resolved:( please give me a suggesstion

Comment: you did that on all 4 textviews ?

Comment: yup, i remove weight from all textviews and edit layout_height = "wrap_content". plz guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That gap is because of the background of `LinearLayout` which you are using in a `row layout`. The height of that background image is much long that's why  it showing the gap between two items.. Try To have the background image with less height to achieve what you require.

Comment: I tend to agree. It seems the bg is very high.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

to

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

never set background in raw_layout..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:background="@drawable/background"         <-----  remove this line
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: not resolved yet:( please give me suggestion how to resolve it??

Answer (score 0):

Remove the background from the root layout of the row and apply it on the `listview`.

> ```
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>       android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
>       android:background="@drawable/background"  <===== Remove background
>       android:orientation="vertical" >
> ```

Apply it in the **report layout**

> ```
> <ListView
>     android:id="@+id/list"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>      android:background="@drawable/background" /> <=== Try applying background in listview.
> ```

Comment: Is your background which you are applying is image or selector? Its an issue with the image which you have applied in the row layout. I guess .